# Automatic animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have a ImageView that needs to be slide in from the bottom. Remain there for 5 sec. And then slide out. How do I do that? There is no user intervention.

Thanks
Rajesh Muthu

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found out a solution.
Create an xml in anim folder called popup_slider.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"  android:duration="100" />
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"   android:startOffset="1000" android:duration="5000" android:zAdjustment="top"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.99" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:startOffset="6000" android:duration="5000" />
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"  android:startOffset="11000"  android:duration="5000" android:zAdjustment="bottom"/>    
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"  android:startOffset="16000"  android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

In Java implement AnimationListener

```
public static void popUpAndDownAnimation(View v) {

Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(localContext, R.anim.popup_slider);  

    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        popUpAdvertisementView.setVisibility(View.GONE);                    
    }
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    }
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        popUpAdvertisementView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);             
    }           
    });
    v.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android has a [set of animation classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) for simple animations on Views.  What you're looking for is a [tween animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#tween-animation).  They provide an example, and it sounds like you could do most of it in XML.  Good luck ^_^